# Very slow when querying large data only using "in" condition with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

a table with 44532 rows,It takes nearly 5s to complete the query when i only use "in" in one column.

describ of table is :

```
Field               Type            Null    Key Default Extra
id                  int(11)         NO      PRI         auto_increment
community_code      varchar(50)     NO      MUL     
extension_worker_no varchar(100)    YES         
apply_id            int(11)         YES     MUL     
segi_cust_id        varchar(100)    YES     MUL     
cust_level          int(11)         YES         1   
cust_name           varchar(255)    YES         
cust_phone          varchar(50)     YES         
cust_status         varchar(255)    YES         
age                 int(5)          YES         
sex                 int(1)          YES         
avatar              varchar(255)    YES         
housing_status      varchar(255)    YES         
house_code          varchar(255)    YES     MUL     
auth_type           varchar(255)    YES         
auth_status         int(1)          YES         1   
auth_time           datetime        YES         
enter_time          datetime        YES         
member_no           varchar(100)    YES         
check_in_status     varchar(255)    YES         2   
in_date             datetime        YES         
invite_code         varchar(128)    YES         
invite_code_status  int(1)          YES         0   
reviewer_no         varchar(60)     YES         
status              int(1)          YES         1   
creater             varchar(60)     YES         SYSTEM  
create_time         datetime        YES         
updater             varchar(60)     YES         
update_time         datetime        YES                 on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Discrimination of the target column is about 0.0019 `SELECT count(DISTINCT community_code)/count(*) FROM table;` i think is very low and scattered.

i execute sql like this

```
SELECT
    t.* 
FROM
    table t
WHERE
    t.community_code IN ('13091264', '13091266', ......)
```

has 20 parameters in the condition,takes nearly 5s

i tried EXPLAIN this sql and i found that its not using index,but when i narrow down the parameters to 5,its using index :

20 parameters :

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys       key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      t                   ALL     index_community_code                45896   67.87       Using where
```

5 parameters :

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys           key                     key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      t                   range   index_community_code    index_community_code    152         3110    100.00      Using index condition
```

i know that mysql will judge whether the index needs to be used or not. i mean,is this normal? or how should i improve this.

my english is not good,thank you all for your help.

Comment: Please add table description and the output of the explain plan. `community_code` is it integer or string ?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE t; - so we can see your indexes.

Comment: What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  How big (in GB) is the table?  What Engine is the table?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Index hint and see if the MySQL picks the index while query execution.
You can try out below options.

**1. USE INDEX Option**

```
SELECT
    t.* 
FROM
    table t USE INDEX (i_index_name)
WHERE
    t.community_code IN ('13091264', '13091266', ......);
```

**2. Force index option**

```
SELECT
    t.* 
FROM
    table t Force INDEX (i_index_name)
WHERE
    t.community_code IN ('13091264', '13091266', ......);
```

Comment: thanks your answer, i just tried the two methods you mentioned, even if used index forced, query is still slow